# Existence of solutions to the linear inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Assume $x = (x_1,\ldots, x_K) \in \mathbb{R}^K$ and $y = (y_1,\ldots, y_K) \in \mathbb{R}^K$. Suppose there exists $1 \leq K' < K$ such that 
$$ x_k <0 \text{ for } 1 \leq k \leq K' \text{ and } x_k \geq 0 \text{ for } k > K',$$ 
and 
$$ y_k \geq 0 \text{ for } 1 \leq k \leq K' \text{ and } y_k < 0 \text{ for } k > K'.$$

What I want is a characterization of $x$ and $y$ so that there exists an $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^K$ such that $\alpha \geq 0$, $\alpha \neq 0$, and $x \cdot \alpha \geq 0$, $y \cdot \alpha \geq 0$.

Can someone help me out? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why have you tagged real analysis here?